# Migrate data from SugarCRM to Odoo?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, etl, sugarcrm

I've got a very large database in SugarCRM. I'm thinking of migrating that database to Odoo. How can I do that? What I can see is SugarCRM and Odoo have completely different database schemas, so I can't think of directly migrating data from SugarCRM to Odoo. I will have to manually import entries in Odoo. Or is there any possibility of programmatically importing the database in Odoo?

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a migration from Joomla to Odoo. Joomla is using MySQL, just like SugarCRM. I started a Python script that runs queries on the MySQL (through `MySQLdb`) and then gets the data into Odoo through [ERPpeek](https://github.com/tinyerp/erppeek), which you can use both standalone and as a library.

With ERPpeek you can easily find out how to work with Odoo's data structure.

It's most convenient to start with the simplest data that you can find.

Here's a bit of code that can get you started. It's not working as is, but I think it's a useful start:

```
from erppeekinit import *
import MySQLdb


def get_dict_cursor():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="odoo_import",
                         passwd="",
                         db="sugarcrm")

    # DictCursor returns mysql rows as dictionary {column_name:value, ...}
    return db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)


def mysql2odoo(table, model_name):
    model = odoo.model(model_name)
    dict_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + table)

    for row in dict_cur.fetchall():

        if model.browse([....  ...]):
            data = {'name': ...
            }
            object = model.create(data)
        else:
            print 'skipping already imported product: ' + row['name']

dict_cur = get_dict_cursor()

table, model = ('your_sugar_crm_table', 'the_odoo.table')
mysql2odoo(table, model)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an extract-transform-load system, where you take data in one schema, extract it from the DB, transform it according to a series of roles, and load it into a new schema.

ETL can be accomplished manually, by custom scripting, or by dedicated ETL tools like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, and CloverETL. What's appropriate depends a lot on the exact nature of the source and destination schemas, how "sane" they are, how well documented they are, how normalized they are, etc.